Pyglet 'window.set_location()' method does not work properly
A most weird problem has occurred to me a couple of days ago during my exploration of the pyglet package: While window.set_location(x,y), window centering on the screen etc. were working fine, at a certain point when I wanted to center  a pyglet window on the Windows screen as usual, the window was totallly off center. See image below.

I then started to investigate the problem in various ways. One of them was to re-install pyglet. The problem insisted.
I also searched in the Web and I couldn't find a single reference about tht problem.
I did a few practical tests and I found out that there was a constant difference between the calculated (expected) window location and the actual one (what appeared on screen). This constant or factor was 1.25. The coordinates on the screen were always increased by that factor in relation the calculated coordinates. I thought this had to do with dpi but the dpi in pyglet seems to apply only to text and more specifically to fonts.
So what the heck is this (pixelling?) factor that modifies positioning on screen and how it is put into effect?
Does anyone know anything about this subject?
Note that this problem is most probably not reproducable, since it occurs unexpectedly and I have no clue about why or how. However, I can provide a simple code, for anyone who would like to try it (It will most probably work fine! :
import pyglet

screen_w, screen_h = 1920, 1080 # Windows screen size
window_w, window_h = 400,400    # pyglet window size

window = pyglet.window.Window(window_w, window_h)
window.set_location((screen_w-window_w)//2, (screen_h-window_h)//2) # Center the window on the screen

pyglet.app.run()


1.25 is most likely the scaling factor of your display on your system. The size of the window also appears to be scaled. Usually there is no general solution for this, there are only system-specific workarounds. So there is no generally correct answer. Maybe this helps How to ignore UI scaling in Pyglet window?

You are too fast!  Sorry, I deleted my reply to your (first) comment because I couldn't edit it anymore (time expired). I wanted to add that your reference explained well the problem and I thanked you. I also asked you why haven't you answered the question instead of commenting on it?

Re "What is the display scale in your system settings for the screen on which the window is displayed?": It is indeed 125%! Never touched that or even knew about that! I had no problem whatsoever in my programming experience with this computer since 5 years ago. There's also the question is why this problem happens only with pyglet and not with any other graphic package (Tkinter, Matplotlib, OpenCV, OpenGL, ...)?  And how comes it started only a couple of days ago? I believe any good programmer would like to have answers for all that ...

I disagree with you here. How would I know that in the first place? And how can "How to ignore UI scaling in Pyglet window?" be a duplicate, if it is not even close to my question? No. I think you are completely wrong here.

You make no sense, man. You don''t even know what a duplicate question is: "Duplicate questions on Stack Overflow are questions that are flagged as being conceptually equivalent to a previously posted question. " Does *"Pyglet 'set_location()' method does not work properly" seem conceptually equivalent to "How to ignore UI scaling in Pyglet window?" to you? I mean, what the heck, man?

Problem solved. It was indeed a DPI issue.
The following action is needed:
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()

